# Repository pushed to Github not showing

Tags: git, github

I am working on an assignment from Coursera and trying to push my local repository to Github. I have tried several times pushing the file, but I do not see the file in Github. Can you please help? This is what I have done:

```
$ git add cachematrix.R

$ git commit cachematrix.R
```

Below is the output from Git Bash:

```
 On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
        deleted:    README
        deleted:    README.md

Untracked files:
        .bash_history
        .gitconfig
        .minttyrc
        .viminfo
        AppData/
        Contacts/
        Desktop/
        Documents/
        Downloads/
        Favorites/
        IntelGraphicsProfiles/
        Links/
        Music/
        NTUSER.DAT
        NTUSER.DAT{b2cacf34-aa21-11e5-8d29-929b663b068b}.TxR.0.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{b2cacf34-aa21-11e5-8d29-929b663b068b}.TxR.1.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{b2cacf34-aa21-11e5-8d29-929b663b068b}.TxR.2.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{b2cacf34-aa21-11e5-8d29-929b663b068b}.TxR.blf
        NTUSER.DAT{b2cacf35-aa21-11e5-8d29-929b663b068b}.TM.blf
        NTUSER.DAT{b2cacf35-aa21-11e5-8d29-929b663b068b}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{b2cacf35-aa21-11e5-8d29-929b663b068b}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
        OneDrive/
        Pictures/
        Saved Games/
        Searches/
        Tracing/
        Videos/
        ntuser.dat.LOG1
        ntuser.dat.LOG2
        ntuser.ini
        "\357\200\233"

no changes added to commit
```

Then, I tried the below:

```
$ git push origin master

Everything up-to-date
```

But, when I go to my repository in Github, the commit is not showing.

Comment: Your list of untracked files looks *very* weird. All those files should *never* appear in a git working directory. I would suggest to start over with a clean clone of the GitHub repository. Also check the syntax of "git commit" (hint: just say "git help commit". "commit" commits the files added to staging. Don't repeat the file name here. If the result says "no changes added", then probably nothing was added. Pushing that will not do anything, of course.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to commit your changes? After you add some changes with `git add FILE`, you can check what is ready for commiting with git status. Then you run `git commit -m ''Commit message'` to commit the changes.

Then you can push those changes with `git push REMOTE BRANCH` where REMOTE is your remote repository and BRANCH the specific branch you are trying to push your code into.

You can check the remote with `git remote -v` to see if it's correctly set. If it doesn't return anything you can set it with `git remote add REMOTE URL`. REMOTE is commonly set to origin. URL in this case refers to the remote repository url whether it's the ssh or http version. You can get it from there.